# Индекс за пределами диапазона.Формула числа перестановок с повторениями

Tags: c#

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int temp, n, k;
    n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    k = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[k, i].Value);
        }
        temp = sum;


    listBox1.Items.Add(Fact(temp)/ 2);

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать формулу числа перестановок с повторениями.

Я пытался посчитать сумму с 1 го столбца, но ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чем, собственно, вопрос? не можете понять, что значит эта ошибка?

Comment: да, не могу  понять, что значит эта ошибка.
И как мне разместить числа с dataGrid вниз, как в формуле n!*n!*n!

Comment: ошибка значит, что вы берете индекс, которого нет в коллекции. А чтобы разместить вниз, вам надо просто делить на них.

Comment: Рекомендация - посмотрите, как пользоваться средствами отладки в `Visual Studio`, тогда вы сами сможете быстро обнаруживать причины ошибок в коде

Comment: Код в тексте не соответствует скриншоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0) - название исключения говорит само за себя. Ваш аргумент (индекс `i`) выходит за допустимые пределы диапазона таблицы.

У вас в скриншоте условие выхода из цикла `i < dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;`. На последней итерации цикла у вас `i = dataGridView1.RowCount`, а индексация в массиве в c# начинается с `0`. поэтому последний элемент массива строк будет иметь индекс `i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1`. Поэтому условие выхода из цикла должно быть такое же, как у вас указано в коде вопроса, а именно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, i].Value);
    }
    temp = sum;
```

индексация в массиве в c# начинается с 0.
на скриншоте было так             `sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);`
Правильно`sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, i].Value);`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]